# How to use custom vibrate pattern in swift or play a double vibrate?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I want to send a double vibrate when a countdown comes to an end, but all of the options I've seen don't work. For example, I've tried the following:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(UInt32(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

But it doesn't work as described. I can't remember if it only vibrates once or not at all, but it does **not** vibrate twice

```
let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()

let feedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
feedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(.error)`enter code here`

let feedbackGenerator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
feedbackGenerator.selectionChanged()
```

None of those worked at all.

And finally I tried this:

```
var counter = 0
var timer : NSTimer?

func vibratePhone() {
    counter++
    switch counter {
    case 1, 2:
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    default:
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

@IBAction func vibrate(sender: UIButton) {
    counter = 0
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.6, target: self, selector: "vibratePhone", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

}`

This does work, but it has a lag of about 1 second prior to playing the first vibrate, which is better than nothing, but not what I'd like to ship with.

What would be ideal is if I could figure out how to use one of the vibrate patterns I created on my iPhone, then save it off to my MBP and use it in my Xcode app, but the closest I can come to this is getting the customer vibrate plist file off my phone. And after that I haven't a clue how to use it (if I can use it at all).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks!